# Transcoding with the GCP Transcoder API results in a time gap

Tags: video, google-cloud-platform, ffmpeg, mpeg-dash, fmp4

I've been trying GCP's [Transcoder API](https://cloud.google.com/transcoder/docs?hl=en) and having trouble with the time randomly becoming shorter than specified in certain cases.

The specific cases are as follows:

1. Specifying `startTimeOffset` and `endTimeOffset` (cut off 2 seconds before and after the video)
2. fMP4 is used as container
3. input video is mp4 with screen recording on iPad Pro

For example, if I don't specify `startTimeOffset` and `endTimeOffset`, the time will not be shortened. Also, there is no problem when MPEG2-TS is specified for container. There may be a problem with the video itself, but I haven't found a clue how to set it up.

I'm not sure whether this is a problem with the Transcoder API or with me.

The test input video: https://gofile.io/d/DUT9rr

```
❯ ffprobe input.mp4
ffprobe version 4.3.1 Copyright (c) 2007-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.28)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.3.1_8 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-videotoolbox --enable-libzmq --enable-libzimg --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'input.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: isommp41mp42
    creation_time   : 2021-02-26T15:08:58.000000Z
  Duration: 00:02:51.15, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 551 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 246 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-02-26T15:08:58.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Audio
    Stream #0:1(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc, bt709/bt709/iec61966-2-1), 1920x1342, 302 kb/s, 12.39 fps, 120 tbr, 600 tbn, 1200 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      rotate          : 180
      creation_time   : 2021-02-26T15:08:58.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
    Side data:
      displaymatrix: rotation of -180.00 degrees
```

```
#!/bin/bash -eu

cat > request.json << EOF
{
  "config": {
    "inputs": [
      {
        key: "input0"
      }
    ],
    "editList": [
      {
        "key": "atom0",
        "inputs": [
          "input0"
        ],
        "startTimeOffset": "2s",
        "endTimeOffset": "169s",
      },
    ],
    "elementaryStreams": [
      {
        "videoStream": {
          "codec": "h265",
          "heightPixels": 480,
          "bitrateBps": 1200000,
          "rateControlMode": "vbr",
          "enableTwoPass": true,
          "frameRate": 30,
          "crfLevel": 31,
          "gopDuration": "3.0s",
        },
        "key": "h265-stream0"
      },
      {
        "videoStream": {
          "codec": "h265",
          "heightPixels": 720,
          "bitrateBps": 1550000,
          "rateControlMode": "vbr",
          "enableTwoPass": true,
          "frameRate": 30,
          "crfLevel": 31,
          "gopDuration": "3.0s",
        },
        "key": "h265-stream1"
      },
      {
        "videoStream": {
          "codec": "h265",
          "heightPixels": 1080,
          "bitrateBps": 2600000,
          "rateControlMode": "vbr",
          "enableTwoPass": true,
          "frameRate": 30,
          "crfLevel": 31,
          "gopDuration": "3.0s",
        },
        "key": "h265-stream2"
      },
      {
        "audioStream": {
          "codec": "aac",
          "bitrateBps": 64000,
          "channelCount": 2,
          "channelLayout": [
            "fl",
            "fr"
          ],
          "sampleRateHertz": 48000
        },
        "key": "audio-stream0"
      },
    ],
    "muxStreams": [
      {
        "key": "media-sd",
        "fileName": "media-sd.m4s",
        "container": "fmp4",
        "elementaryStreams": [
          "h265-stream0",
        ],
        "segmentSettings": {
          "individualSegments": true
        },
      },
      {
        "key": "media-hd",
        "fileName": "media-hd.m4s",
        "container": "fmp4",
        "elementaryStreams": [
          "h265-stream1",
        ],
        "segmentSettings": {
          "individualSegments": true
        },
      },
      {
        "key": "media-fhd",
        "fileName": "media-fhd.m4s",
        "container": "fmp4",
        "elementaryStreams": [
          "h265-stream2",
        ],
        "segmentSettings": {
          "individualSegments": true
        },
      },
      {
        "key": "audio-only",
        "fileName": "audio-only.m4s",
        "container": "fmp4",
        "elementaryStreams": [
          "audio-stream0"
        ],
        "segmentSettings": {
          "individualSegments": true
        },
      },
    ],
    "manifests": [
      {
        "fileName": "manifest-h265.mpd",
        "type": "DASH",
        "muxStreams": [
          "media-sd",
          "media-hd",
          "media-fhd",
          "audio-only",
        ]
      },
    ]
  }
}
EOF

curl -X POST \
-H "Authorization: Bearer "$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token) \
-H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
-d @request.json \
https://transcoder.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/MY_PROJECT/locations/asia-east1/jobTemplates?jobTemplateId=test-template
```

```
#!/bin/bash -eu

cat > request.json << EOF
{
  "inputUri": "gs://my-bucket/input.mp4",
  "outputUri": "gs://my-bucket/output/",
  "templateId": "test-template"
}
EOF

curl -X POST \
-H "Authorization: Bearer "$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token) \
-H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
-d @request.json \
https://transcoder.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/MY_PROJECT/locations/asia-east1/jobs
```

The following is a ffprobe of the resulting manifest file, which is 2 seconds shorter than specified. (expected: `00:02:47.00`, actual: `00:02:45.00`) In this case, it's a 2-second gap, but it can be 10 seconds or 30 seconds, and it varies from video to video.

```
❯ ffprobe manifest-h265.mpd
ffprobe version 4.3.1 Copyright (c) 2007-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.28)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.3.1_8 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-videotoolbox --enable-libzmq --enable-libzimg --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
Input #0, dash, from 'manifest-h265.mpd':
  Duration: 00:02:45.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 0 kb/s
  Program 0
    Stream #0:0: Video: hevc (Main) (hvc1 / 0x31637668), yuv420p(tv, bt709/unknown/unknown), 686x480, 112 kb/s, 30 fps, 120 tbr, 10k tbn, 30 tbc
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 113679
      id              : 113679
    Stream #0:1: Video: hevc (Main) (hvc1 / 0x31637668), yuv420p(tv, bt709/unknown/unknown), 1030x720, 205 kb/s, 30 fps, 120 tbr, 10k tbn, 30 tbc
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 189219
      id              : 189219
    Stream #0:2: Video: hevc (Main) (hvc1 / 0x31637668), yuv420p(tv, bt709/unknown/unknown), 1544x1080, 384 kb/s, 30 fps, 120 tbr, 10k tbn, 30 tbc
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 358043
      id              : 358043
    Stream #0:3: Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 65 kb/s
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 70245
      id              : 70245
```

The following is the time as specified for h264 + MPEG2-TS + Apple HLS.

```
❯ ffprobe manifest-h264.m3u8 | pbcopy
ffprobe version 4.3.1 Copyright (c) 2007-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.28)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.3.1_8 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-videotoolbox --enable-libzmq --enable-libzimg --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
[hls @ 0x7fe23100f200] Opening 'h264-sd-ts.m3u8' for reading
[hls @ 0x7fe23100f200] Skip ('#EXT-X-VERSION:4')
[hls @ 0x7fe23100f200] Opening 'h264-hd-ts.m3u8' for reading
[hls @ 0x7fe23100f200] Skip ('#EXT-X-VERSION:4')
[hls @ 0x7fe23100f200] Opening 'h264-fhd-ts.m3u8' for reading
[hls @ 0x7fe23100f200] Skip ('#EXT-X-VERSION:4')
[hls @ 0x7fe23100f200] Opening 'h264-sd0000000000.ts' for reading
[hls @ 0x7fe23100f200] Opening 'h264-hd0000000000.ts' for reading
[hls @ 0x7fe23100f200] Opening 'h264-fhd0000000000.ts' for reading
Input #0, hls, from 'manifest-h264.m3u8':
  Duration: 00:02:47.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 0 kb/s
  Program 0
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 511576
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p, 686x480, 120 tbr, 90k tbn, 2000k tbc
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 511576
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 511576
  Program 1
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 793711
    Stream #0:2: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p, 1030x720, 120 tbr, 90k tbn, 2000k tbc
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 793711
    Stream #0:3: Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 793711
  Program 2
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 1305288
    Stream #0:4: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p, 1544x1080, 120 tbr, 90k tbn, 2000k tbc
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 1305288
    Stream #0:5: Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 1305288
```

Comment: This might be a bug with the Transcoder API, which isn't generally available yet. Hopefully you talked to Google support about this.

Comment: Thanks! I've given up using the transcoder API.